# Proper way to validate dynamic path variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I want to find and validates dynamic path variable.

User can enter url and dynamic path variable in input box like below.

```
http://localhost:3000/{abc}
https://google.com/{a}/{bb}/{ccc}
```

Dynamic path variable is optional. Therefore url that does not have path variable is also fine.

However, if user wants to add dynamic path variable, it must start with '/{' and ends with '}'.

Therefore urls below are not valid.

```
https://google.com/{}
https://helloWorld/{aaa
http://localhost:3000/aaa}
http://localhost:9999/{aaa}}
```

Here is what I did.

first I split url using '/' and create a new array starts from 3rd index to the last index.

```
const url = 'https://google.com/{a}/{bb}/{ccc'

const splitUrl = url.split('/') // ['https:', '', 'google.com', '{a}', '{bb}', '{ccc']

const pathVaraibles = splitUrl.slice(3) // ['{a}', '{bb}', '{ccc']
```

Then I just need to check `pathVariables` array whether all elements in the array are valid variables.

Could this be the proper way to validate dynamic path variables in url?

Comment: I think you can make use of [the URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). Example usage: `new URL('https://google.com/{a}/{bb}/{ccc') // { pathname: '/%7Ba%7D/%7Bbb%7D/%7Bccc', /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
function isValidUrlWithPathVariable(url) {
  const splitUrl = url.split('/');

  const pathVariables = splitUrl.slice(3).filter(i=>i);
  if (pathVariables.length === 0) {
    //URL does not have any path variables, which is valid
    return true;
  }
  const regex = /^{[^{}]+}$/;
  //check all the path variables against the regex
  for (let i = 0; i < pathVariables.length; i++) {
    if (!regex.test(pathVariables[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}


const urlValid1 = 'https://google.com';
const urlValid2 = 'http://localhost:3000/{aaa}';
console.log(isValidUrlWithPathVariable(urlValid1));  //true
console.log(isValidUrlWithPathVariable(urlValid2));  //true

const urlInvalid1 = 'https://google.com/{}';
const urlInvalid2 = 'https://helloWorld/{aaa';
const urlInvalid3 = 'http://localhost:3000/aaa}';
const urlInvalid4 = 'http://localhost:9999/{aaa}}';
console.log(isValidUrlWithPathVariable(urlInvalid1));//false
console.log(isValidUrlWithPathVariable(urlInvalid2));//false
console.log(isValidUrlWithPathVariable(urlInvalid3));//false
console.log(isValidUrlWithPathVariable(urlInvalid4));//false
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of these assumptions are incorrect, you'll have to adjust the final regular expressions. Everything depends a bit on what you're ultimately trying to do.

Are you trying to validate the URLs as well, or are we just assuming they're valid & only want to look at the dynamic component? If so, that's covered well in this SO question: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/3577502).

Secondly, what if we have a URL of the form: `https://website.com/User/{userid}/Profile`: Is this a valid dynamic URL? I'm going to assume, "yes", but all examples "end with" the dynamic portion.

Thirdly, the dynamic strings you're using are of the form `{aaa}`, `{abc}`, etc. but you didn't really put any restrictions on them in the question. I'd assume "alphabetic" or "alphanumeric" but obviously other people have assumed they can be "anything that's not a curly brace" (i.e. `[^{}]+` in a regex is "one or more elements `+` that aren't in the set `[^]` containing the values `{}`.")

Are you always using "fully qualified URLs" or can they also be "root relative"? E.g. `https://localhost:3010/User/Profile/{userid}` vs `/User/Profile/{userid}`. I'm assuming fully qualified, but there's benefits to using relative URLs in an app.

---

I'd definitely use a similar approach to [@Mamun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197695/3577502) and use a regular expression (regex) as well.

Leveraging the fact that, ["...curly braces are unsafe characters, and are not valid in URIs..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/curly-brackets-in-urls) I'd just:

- Validate that the URL matches your expected form with a very basic check,
- Use a slightly different regex to extract the path variables,
- (Run whatever your code would be to dynamically replace those vars),
- Run a final regex over the URL to determine it's valid (or just "use it" & trust nothing's gone awry).

```js
// Starts with "http(s)://" then skips to the first "/"
// Checks it's either: /{<alphanumeric>} (e.g. /{abc})
// Or path component doesn't have `{}` in it at all (e.g. /Profile)
// * Repeat 0 or more times (e.g. http://a.com OR https://b.com/{a}/{b}/Test/{c}/)
function isDynamicUrl(url) {
    const testUrlRegex = /https*:\/\/[^/]+(\/({\w+})|([^{}]*))*?$/
    return testUrlRegex.test(url)
}

// Variables pulled from "somewhere"
const props = {
    userId: 5,
    area: "Designs",
}

const path = "https://example.com/{userId}/{area}/Index"
var url = ""

// matches will be of the form: [["/{userId}", "userId"], ["/{area}", "area"]]
if (isDynamicUrl(path)) {
    const replacementRegex = /\/{(\w+)}/g;
    url = path.replace(replacementRegex, (match, group1) => "/" + props[group1])
}

// url == "https://example.com/5/Designs/Index"
console.log(url)
```

For testing regular expressions, I'd recommend a site like https://regexr.com/ which freely lets you test an expression against a block of text to validate it. If you paste my expression into a site like that, it'll give a clearer explanation of how it works than I could probably describe.

You may need to make some small changes for testing there, e.g. I used multiple lines so I had to use the `/gm` flag (anchors like $ will respect newlines) & also account for `\n` (newline) when testing:
/(https*://[^/\n]*)(/([^{}\n]*)|({\w+}))*?$/gm

Comment: before the pathname validation, url validation is proceeded whether the url is  "fully qualified URLs" or not and yes url such as 'https://website.com/User/{userid}/Profile' is also valid.
There is also rule that must be applied to dynamic string. It allows only english and _ in terms of naming.

Comment: I used `\w+` in my example, which matches one or more "word characters" (alphanumeric ASCII & underscore). If you want to exclude digits you'd use something like `[A-Za-z_]+` which is explicitly capital & lower-case ASCII letters & underscore. Though both would exclude diacritics / accented characters, which can show up in loanwords (e.g. entrée).